# Matplotlib get all axes artist objects for ArtistAnimation?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to make an animation using ArtistAnimation like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ims = []
for i in range(60):
    x = np.linspace(0,i,1000)
    y = np.sin(x)
    im = ax.plot(x,y, color='black')
    ims.append(im)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

plt.show()
```

This animates a sine wave growing across the figure. Currently I'm just adding the Lines2D object returned by `ax.plot()` to `ims`. However, I would like to potentially draw multiple overlapping plots on the Axes and adjust the title, legend and x-axis range for each frame. How do I get an object that I can add to `ims` after plotting and making all the changes I want for each frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list you supply to `ArtistAnimation` should be a list of lists of artists, one list per frame.

```
artist_list = [[line1a, line1b, title1], [line2a, line2b, title2], ...]
```

where the first list is shown in the first frame, the second list in the second frame etc.

The reason your code works is that `ax.plot` returns a list of lines (in your case only a list of a single line).

In any case, the following might be a more understandable version of your code where an additional text is animated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

artist_list = []
for i in range(60):
    x = np.linspace(0,i,1000)
    y = np.sin(x)
    line, = ax.plot(x,y, color='black')
    text = ax.text(i,0,i)
    artist_list.append([line, text])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, artist_list, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

plt.show()
```

In general, it will be hard to animate changing axes limits with `ArtistAnimation`, so if that is an ultimate goal consider using a `FuncAnimation` instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for clarifying that, I didn't really understand how ArtistAnimation worked. I looked at FuncAnimation a bit, but ArtistAnimation seemed more intuitive. I would think it would work for me, all I need to do is extract the list of artist objects from the Axes after I scale the x-axis, isn't that possible? Lets say I have some function plot_sines(A) that returns a Figure and Axes object with cos(A) and sin(A) plotted overlayed and formatted nicely, how can I extract the needed artist objects to animate those? Your example still uses the artist object directly returned by ax.plot()

Comment: That's exactly the problem I was talking about when trying to animate *everything*. So one hard constraint is of course that an animation runs inside a figure. If your function creates a new figure in each call, it cannot be used. Apart, it should be possible to animate everything, but at rather high cost in memory consumption. Personally I would rather use `FuncAnimation` from the start. It's not at all unintuitive and especially if you have a function `plot_sines(A)` that might actually already be close to what you need for it to work.